# Add Administrator to User Profile Server via Powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile-service

I was recently directed to an article that explains how to add a user to the permissions list for the User Profile Service using Powershell, which worked a treat. [[My original question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51610/user-profile-service-can-add-my-user-to-administrators-but-not-permissions/53417#53417)]

I'm now looking for a way to add a user to the Administrators list for the User Profile Service, again using Powershell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Assign administration of a User Profile service application (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721057%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

```
$serviceapp = Get-SPServiceApplication <guid>
$security = Get-SPServiceApplicationSecurity $serviceapp -Admin
$principalUser1 = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -Identity "<domain\user>" -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName
Grant-SPObjectSecurity $security -Principal $principalUser1 -Rights "Full Control"
Set-SPServiceApplicationSecurity $serviceapp -ObjectSecurity $security -Admin
```

Comment: Thanks again, rj (you helped me once before, hence the 'again'). Getting that link/code was the exact purpose of the question :)

Comment: No problem, happy to help.